# jQuery - animate + show() in a queue in for cycle

Tags: jquery

I'm having a very specific problem, I don't even know what to look for in Google...
I'm trying to create an animated letter. There's a pen and 5 lines which are in a separate  tag, all within one container element, positioned relatively, having their own ID, and the lines are hidden (all on their place, where they should appear). The animation is like this: the pen moves diagonally, a line appears, the pen moves to the beginning of the new line, repeat 5 times, pen goes back to default position, lines disappear.
I didn't want to write the animation code for all 5 cycles separately, so I inserted the animations into a queue using a for cycle. Everything is working fine, except the silliest thing - I can't get the current line number to show. Here's the code:

```
var penAnimating = false;

function animateLetter() {
    var pen = $('#form_decor_pen');
    var startRight = pen.css('right');
    var startTop = pen.css('top');

    if (!penAnimating) {
        penAnimating = true;

        for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            pen.animate( {
                right: '-=26',
                top: '-=10',
            },{ 
                duration: 600,
                queue: 'penAnimation'
            });
```

Here' the problem part:

```
pen.queue('penAnimation', function(next) {          
    //var line = $('#form_header_decor :nth-child(' + i.toString() + ')')
    var line = $('#line_' + i.toString())
    line.show();
    //alert(line.id);
    next(); 
})
```

The problem is, i always outputs 5 - the number at which the cycle ends.

```
            if (i<5) {
                pen.animate({
                    right: '+=26',
                    top: '+=20',
                   },{
                    duration: 300,
                    queue: 'penAnimation'
                });
            } else {
                pen.animate({
                    right: startRight,
                    top: startTop,
                   },{
                    duration: 300,
                    queue: 'penAnimation',
                    complete: function() {
                        penAnimating = false;
                    }
                });
            }​
         }
       pen.dequeue('penAnimation');
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone has any idea ?
It seems like the number is being inserted in the queue after the cycle. But why ? And how con I overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a for loop that has asynchronous calls in it the value of the for variable is going to be the last value. Unless you put the code in a closure.

Change the for loop to a for-loop-with-a-closure.

```
    for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) { 
    (function(i){
    // the second i is now in a closure.
    })(i);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but I still have no idea how to implement it exactly. Could you please specify how exactly should I edit the code in the middle section to work ? I tried several ways, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Is there something else you need?